# Apply hover on all elements except the first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have various elements and when I hover them, I want all of them to have a background with the exception of the first child.

Here's my CSS selector:

```
#OfficeUI .iconHolder img:hover:not(:first-child) { background-color: #CDE6F7; }
```

What's wrong with this?

**Relevant HTML**

```
        <div class="officeui-position-absolute iconHolder">
            <!-- Provides the images on the top left of the ribbon. -->
            <top-Images-Container>
                <span ng-repeat="icon in icons">
                    <img src="{{icon.Icon}}" />
                </span>
            </top-Images-Container>    
        </div>
```

Comment: Where's the relevant html?

Comment: #OfficeUI .iconHolder img:not(:first-child):hover { background-color: #CDE6F7; }

Comment: I've added the HTML as an update.

Comment: You don't have multiple imgs on the same level ... so first-child isn't gonna work

Comment: @Danko I didn't understand that I didn't saw that issue. Now it's resolved. Thanks

Comment: Np mate glad to help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
p:not(:first-child):hover {background-color: red;}
```

```html
<p>first</p>
<p>second</p>
<p>third</p>
```

Comment: However, your snipped it's working, it isn't in my particular case. I'm using AngularJS but I don't think that changes anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `nth-child` selector. `n+2` makes it select all but the 1st element.

```css
li:nth-child(n+2):hover {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you can use:

```
    #OfficeUI .iconHolder img:nth-child(n + 2):hover
```